# AngularJS - Get selected option from select

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

So, i'm trying to make a simple product order form for my app. I have a select element in Ionic popup, which shows products name and price (which are separate fields in the database). Now i need to transfer third piece of information - the id - of the product that user has selected to INSERT query which will store the order into database, but i just can't seem to do it. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here:

```
$scope.openPopup = function(id, name){
    $scope.data = {};

  // Custom popup
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
     template: 'Choose product: <select ng-model="data.selected">\n\
                                    <option ng-repeat="product in products" ng-value="product.id">{{product.name}} - Price: {{product.price}}€</option>\n\
                                    </select>',
     title: 'Order form',
     scope: $scope,     
     buttons: [
        { text: 'Cancel' }, {
           text: '<b>Save</b>',
           type: 'button-positive',
              onTap: function(e) {

                 if (!$scope.data.selected) {
                    //don't allow the user to close unless he enters model...
                    console.log("no data");
                       e.preventDefault();
                 } else {
                     console.log("Product: " + $scope.data.selected);
                    var selectedProduct = $scope.data.selected;
                    // INSERT query here
                     }, function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
                 }
              }
        }
     ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Tapped!', res);
  });    
};
```

Problem is, code doesn't go to the else-branch, because $scope.data.selected is not set. But shouldn't ng-value bind ng-model of the SELECT element into the OPTION elements id? I've heard that using ng-options is also an option, but i don't know if that will be able to present multiple values in one option element.

The code is getting products from earlier part of the file, which i won't post here because it's working fine (the product name appears in select element).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, but it looks like you are not selecting a default value for `$scope.data.selected`. So if `onTap` is executed without any option being selected by the user, `$scope.data.selected` will be empty.

Also, can the ID ever be 0? If so, then the `if (!$scope.data.selected)` branch would execute.

Comment: I have tested it by selecting an option though, and all the id's are more than 0. I'm not sure why it isn't getting it.